# Merging ordered lists in F#, Expecting a 'a but given a 'a -> a' list

Tags: list, types, f#, mergesort, type-mismatch

I'm trying to implement a merge sort in F#, as I'm trying to learn functional programming. However I have run into problems with this auxiliary function merge. Hopefully someone could point me in the right direction. Keep in mind I only have a rudimentary understanding of F#.

```
let rec merge a b =
match a, b with
|q, [] -> q
|[], p -> p 
|q::q', p::p' when q<p -> q::merge q' p::p'
|q::q', p::p' when p<q -> p::merge q::q' p';;

merge [1;3;5;7;9] [2;4;6;8;10];;
```

Console output:

```
Uge2.fsx(96,34): error FS0001: Type mismatch. Expecting a
'a    
but given a
'a list    
The resulting type would be infinite when unifying ''a' and ''a list'
> 

Uge2.fsx(99,1): error FS0039: The value or constructor 'merge' is not defined
```

Any suggestions regarding the code are more than welcome. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`q :: merge q' p :: p'` is understood as `(q :: (merge q' p)) :: p'`

That implies that `p` type must be both a `'a` (some thing) and `'a list` (a list of those things)

What you really want is `q :: merge q' (p :: p')`
Or seeing that `p :: p'` is `b`

You can rewrite it `q :: merge q' b`

Comment: Makes perfect sense! Thanks a bunch. I did not realize that a and b were within scope either.

Comment: @Sebastian IMHO you should take a look at [F# for Fun & Profit](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/troubleshooting-fsharp/) it contains a lot of usefull info

Comment: Will certainly do that!